# Convert string value in Time format in robotium

Tags: java, robotium

I want to convert following **String value in time format**.

```
String convertInTime="10:20 AM"
```

And then I want to **round up to "11:00 AM**"

How should I do this?

Comment: Sounds like you want to parse to an appropriate format (e.g. `LocalTime` in Joda Time), perform any rounding you want, and then reformat. What have you tried so far, and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you can use the apache commons library, if so then please refer to: **org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils.round(Date date, int field)**:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html#round(java.util.Date, int)

The first parameter is a **java.util.Date** that you can create with a help of **java.text.SimpleDateFormat**, and the second parameter is a constant from a Calendar class like **Calendar.HOUR**.

If you can't employ the apache commons library check how they do it:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html#line.645.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion...but i am not allowed to use apache common library